# ATL COM: Access Event Methods From Other Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, atl

I'm implementing a COM interface to an existing VS2010 C++ MFC-application. Most parts of the COM interface interaction works great, but I am confused of how to trigger COM events from another thread that the one where the COM interface is running / defined. The application is multi-threaded with one main thread running the COM interface and handling GUI changes (**thread 1**) and one thread to receive incoming messages from a C-library (**thread 2**).

For certain messages received in thread 2 I want to notify the COM clients by sending a COM event. I have read many threads ([Firing COM Event From Another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644598/firing-a-com-event-from-another-thread) is one of them) and [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693316%28VS.85%29.aspx) / [CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is mentioned. Using Google I can't seem to find any usage of these methods that makes any sense to me; I just don't understand how to implement these functions and if they really will help me.

Relevant code parts:

**TestCOM.idl:** (the interface definition)

```
 interface ITestCOM: IDispatch
{
    [id(1), helpstring("method Test")] HRESULT Test();
};

dispinterface _ITestCOMEvents
{
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(1), helpstring("event ExecutionOver")] HRESULT TestEvent();
};

coclass TestAppCOM
{
    [default] interface ITestCOM;
    [default, source] dispinterface _ITestCOMEvents;
};
```

**ITestCOMEvents_CP.h** (VS generated class for Connection Points / events)

```
template<class T>
class CProxy_ITestCOMEvents : 
   public ATL::IConnectionPointImpl<T, &__uuidof(_ITestCOMEvents)>
{
public:
    HRESULT Fire_TestEvent()
    {
       HRESULT hr = S_OK;
       T * pThis = static_cast<T *>(this);
       int cConnections = m_vec.GetSize();
       for (int iConnection = 0; iConnection < cConnections; iConnection++)
       {
          pThis->Lock();
          CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(iConnection);
          pThis->Unlock();
...
```

**TestCOM.h** (class implementing the methods and CProxy_ITestCOMEvents class)

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTestCOM :
   public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
   public CComCoClass<CTestCOM, &CLSID_TestCOM>,
   public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<CTestCOM>,
   public CProxy_ITestCOMEvents<CTestCOM>,
   public IDispatchImpl<IMecAppCOM, &IID_ITestCOM, &LIBID_TestLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
   static CTestCOM * p_CTestCOM;

CTestCOM()
{
    p_CTestCOM = this;
}
```

**Incoming.CPP** (a class running on thread 2 that should trigger an event in the following case statement)

```
case INCOMING_EVENT_1:
// Trigger Fire_TestEvent in thread 1
// CTestCOM::p_CTestCOM->Fire_TestEvent(); trigger event on thread 2
```

In the code above you can find my current workaround for this problem which is to create a pointer object p_CTestCOM that will allow any class running on thread 1 to trigger the COM events. Thread 2 can access that object but it would trigger it in thread 2, which wouldn't work. To solve this all methods defined in Incoming.CPP could post a message (using PostMessage()) to thread 1 which would use p_CTestCOM to access and send the COM event. This would work, but I am sure there must be a better (and safer) solution that more accurately follows the COM design principles.

I someone could shed some light I would be most grateful!

Comment: The technique you're looking for is called *marshalling*. I had thought it was only between processes but it appears to be available to threads as well. See for starters http://support.microsoft.com/kb/206076

Comment: I successfully used GIT to marshall and receive a pointer to my ITestCOM interface. However, I can't access the Fire_TestEvent() event from the ITestCOM interface and I don't want to be forced to add public methods to the COM library that will only trigger the event (like HRESULT TriggerTestEvent();). Is there any way to access the Fire_Event methods or create private methods in the library that only the application will access and not any client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roman R. provides some good options but there is a better alternative, IMO: you can marshal the listeners to the thread which fires the event. As advising the listeners is typically done inside `IConnectionPointImpl` class in an ATL project, you 'just' need to modify the default `IConnectionPointImpl` to do the marshalling for you (e.g. via [GIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is simpler that marshaling API).

The big advantage is that the rest of the code remains almost the same as before, so no message passing or synchronization is needed - only the generated *CP.h file needs to be updated.

The implementation is discussed in Microsoft knowledge base article KB280512 which seems to be removed now, but there is an [improved implementation by PJ Naughter](http://naughter.wordpress.com/2007/01/23/iconnectionpointimplmt/) which you can use to replace the default implementation.

[Here's the version that I use](https://gist.github.com/zdeslav/5582456), based on the missing KB article.
The usage is simple, just rename the [class in the generated CP.h file](https://gist.github.com/zdeslav/5582456#file-gistfile1-cpp) and modify `m_vec.GetAt` parts, as described in the gist I have linked.

Comment: The article is still available in other languages :-) for example in french http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280512/fr (the attached sample is not downloadable unfortunately)

Comment: I used the supplied IConnectionPointImplMT implementation but the application throws an exception when I try to trigger events. I updated the Fire_TestEvent() function in my original post. The exception is thrown at line:
CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(iConnection);

Comment: @user2383179, actually, the comment on line 69 of `ATLCPImplMT.hpp` explains the required change (and now also in the gist). I suggest reading the implementation anyway - it will help with potential problems

Comment: Thank you! This is a great change I could never have figured out myself! I now use the p_CTestCOM object and the event is sent as it should from any thread calling it :)

Comment: A newer and modified version of of `ATLCPImplMT.h` that works with newer versions of ATL can be found at http://www.naughter.com/gpscom2.html

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to start with is the threading model of your COM object. It is is MTA, then you might want to simply initialize your worker thread respectively with COM, with `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` and fire events right from there.

If the object is STA, which is most likely the case, and what might be necessary e.g. to well integrate the object with some environments, then you need to fire events from the main thread, and to get there from the worker thread you need to use some synchronization. For example, on your worker thread you discover a need to fire an event. You code might set a flag or an internal synchronization object (such as event) so that main thread code would eventually notice it and proceed with raising an external event from there.

Another common solution for STA COM object is to create in advance a hidden/message-only window so that a worker thread could post a message on it. The message will be dispatched to the window's procedure on window creation thread, that is on STA thread and the message handler would be a safe place to fire COM event from.

Alternatively you can create an internal COM object and marshal it into worker thread to create a proxy/stub pair, and have your call from worker thread automatically converted into call of your method on main thread through marhsaling. This is workable but inferior to window messaging in almost every way: your interface/object needs to be suitable for proxy/stub pair creation, COM call is blocking while with a windows message you always have a choice between `SendMessage` and `PostMessage`, and it is the latter you wlil want to prefer to avoid deadlocks in interthread communication.

Comment: CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) on the Thread made GIT work for me. Now I have a reference to the ITestCOM interface. However, I would like to trigger the Fire_Event functions without using the public methods of the ITestCOM interface. Is there anyway I can do this? It feels like unnecessary overhead to add new methods just to trigger the event functions.

Comment: Sorry, that was a type with `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`, I corrected text above. With GIT you don't need to add public methods to `ITestCOM`. Instead you put onto GIT sink interfaces (`IDispatch`), but you need to update `IConnectionPointImpl` class so that it takes sink interface from GIT and not from internal collection (it's `IConnectionPointImplMT` on Zdeslav's answer). This is a great solution as well, just keep in mind that it's also a blocking call into original thread and you need to be aware of possible deadlocks when you are terminating the worker thread.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. `ITestCOM` is of type `IDispatch` and only contain (public) methods exposed to clients (see the .IDL declaration above). I could add more methods to that interface but then the client would be able to trigger them as well. `CTestCOM` can access all the `Fire_Event` methods but I am not allowed to use GIT on that object (not of type `IUnknown`).