# Data being lost when sent via a different thread over COM server - previously worked in VC6, now broken in VS2010

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, com

I have been bit by a lot of little problems in conversion from VC6 to VS2010, but having problems solving this one.  Below is the delegate used when sending data from my class to the COM server.

EDIT 2:  Added code to check varResult.

```
HRESULT Fire_Msg(BSTR Msg)
{
    CComVariant varResult;
    T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
    int nConnectionIndex;
    CComVariant* pvars = new CComVariant[1];

    int nConnections = m_vec.GetSize();

    for (nConnectionIndex = 0; nConnectionIndex < nConnections; nConnectionIndex++)
    {
        pT->Lock();
        CComPtr<IUnknown> sp = m_vec.GetAt(nConnectionIndex);
        pT->Unlock();
        IDispatch* pDispatch = reinterpret_cast<IDispatch*>(sp.p);
        if (pDispatch != NULL)
        {
            pvars[0] = Msg;
            DISPPARAMS disp = { pvars, NULL, 1, 0 };
            pDispatch->Invoke(0x1, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &disp, &varResult, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }

    delete [] pvars;

    // Changed to display what happens to varResult.
    if (varResult.scode != S_OK)
    {
        // Do some error handling...  (later)
        return varResult.scode;
    }
    else
    {
        return varResult.scode;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:  From either working or non-working, varResult returns S_OK.  No difference.

When I break on this line, when sent from the main process or a thread, the data looks correct:

```
pDispatch->Invoke(0x1, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &disp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Edit:
I have pictures of working and non-working.  It really just shows that when called from a thread started from threadex, the data is properly set in "disp" and there is no problem doing the "pDispatch->Invoke"..
Working:
[image: working]

Non-working:
[image: nonworking]
:End Edit

In the other application, I have the following code to answer the dispatched data:

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CGenRTEvent, CCmdTarget)
    //{{AFX_DISPATCH_MAP(CGenRTEvent)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CGenRTEvent, "OnMsgStr", OnMsgStr, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CGenRTEvent, "OnMsg", OnMsg, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CGenRTEvent, "OnEndRun", OnEndRun, VT_EMPTY, "")
    DISP_FUNCTION(CGenRTEvent, "OnProgress", OnProgress, VT_EMPTY, VTS_I4 VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CGenRTEvent, "OnISocket", OnISocket, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
//  DISP_FUNCTION(CGenRTEvent, "OnMsg", OnMsg, VT_EMPTY, VTS_PVARIANT)
    //}}AFX_DISPATCH_MAP
END_DISPATCH_MAP()

BEGIN_INTERFACE_MAP(CGenRTEvent, CCmdTarget)
    INTERFACE_PART(CGenRTEvent, DIID__IGenRTEvents, Dispatch)
END_INTERFACE_MAP()

void CGenRTEvent::OnMsgStr(LPCTSTR strMsg) 
{
    m_pFrame->OnMsgStr(strMsg);
}
```

When used from the main thread (inside the first application), OnMsgStr is properly raised.  When done from a different thread, OnMsgStr is never raised.  This had been working solidly in VC6, but VS2010 doesn't like it.

Edit: My question is, how can I prevent the data from being lost?  I am fairly sure the reason is tied to calling this from a different thread, but don't know how to fix it.

Any suggestions or input is appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are blind as a bat as long as you don't look at the Invoke() return value.  So are we.

Comment: I had looked in the debugger for any differences between them and didn't see any, but have modified the code and double-checked.

Comment: There's lots of code missing.  This seems to be part of a template, what is `T` supposed to be?  Does `GetAt` call `AddRef` on the returned pointer?  Are you returning a `CComPtr` (don't) or a raw pointer (you should `Attach` the smart pointer to it instead of assigning)?  Is the interface pointer always accessed in the same apartment (if not, you must marshal it)?  The `reinterpret_cast` to `IDispatch*` is simply wrong, you **must** `QueryInterface`.  You should check `Invoke`'s return value instead of `varResult`.  Even then, you're not checking the variant's type (`.vt`).

Comment: You have race conditions: you're fetching the vector's size and you're iterating the vector, all **outside** the lock.  What prevents another thread from growing or shrinking the vector, or releasing the current connection point, simultaneously?  You're checking the last `varResult` (for what it's worth; you should be checking each `Invoke`'s result).  You should call `VariantClear` before reusing `varResult` as an out argument (you wouldn't have to for an in-out argument).

Comment: @PauloMadeira - Thanks so much for the response.  For the first part of your comment, T literally just looks like this: template <class T>.  I didn't write this code and the person who did is long gone, but it was functional.  As I do internet searching, this link here: [link[(https://www.falconview.org/svn/FalconView/trunk/public/fvw_core/NITFSourcesCtrl/NITFSourcesCtrlCP.h) just seems to have too much in common to be coincidence.  I look forward to re-writing per your suggestion and I will do that first thing tomorrow, and post results.

Comment: @PauloMadeira - Having said that, I have exhaustively stepped this through in the debugger.  nConnections is only ever 1.  Second, the data for "disp" is always correct.  It is always BSTR.  Invoke always returns S_OK.  The data "appears" to go out correctly with no problem.  On the other side, the event is only raised when sent from the main process.  When sent from a thread, it is always lost even though the data at that point appears to send properly through the Invoke.  (The pictures I hope show this...)  Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, that's the code ATL generates when implementing a connection point through a VS wizard.  You may want to keep that code (e.g. it might be regenerated if you recreate the connection point container implementation through the wizard), although the cast is a serious flaw.  Check if the sink object implements `IDispatch` (or a default dispatching derivate) as its first interface.  If it doesn't, then try making so.  Anyway, I advise to replace the cast with `QueryInterface`, if you're supposed to expose your object to the world.

Comment: Also, as I suspected initially, this is most probably a (lack of) marshaling problem, check out [KB280512 (internet archive version)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111217005258/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280512).  Howcome it worked in VC6, that's a mistery, are you sure you didn't add the multiple threads problem in the transition?

Comment: @PauloMadeira - Positive problems were not added in transition.  Based off the above KB, I was able to find another implementation that was not that far off from what I had.  [link](https://naughter.wordpress.com/2007/01/23/gpscom-v1-04/)   This allowed me to address your concerns AND fix my problems.  If you would like to answer, I will mark you for credit.  I wouldn't have found it if not for googling the KB you gave.  Thanks for all your help ...  if you have time, look at my other question?  I'm stuck on that one too.

Comment: Although I appreciate your intention, you should be the one answering, even to your own question.  If someone with the same problem finds this question, (s)he'll find out the correct answer immediately without searching for the accepted one.

Comment: Also, be aware that having a lock around event dispatch calls on the `Fire_` methods might cause a deadlock, e.g. if the object is in the MTA and the event handler is in another apartment (or process) and the event handler calls something from the object recursively, which in turn gets handled in a different thread which might call `Fire_` events.  The safest approach (albeit not the most efficient) is to copy the whole array, much like when getting an enumerator for connection points.

Comment: In another question, you mention switching the MFC project from "Multithreaded" to "Multithreaded DLL".  You should avoid this kind of change until you have completed the transition, otherwise you'll observe new effects and you'll be fixing new problems.  Later, you won't easily know what changed **due to the transition** and what changed that **has nothing to do with the transition**, so analyzing the impact of future changes that will touch the changed code will become harder.  For instance, remember that with the DLL, the MFC global state is shared between modules, but not with the LIB.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Unfortunately, a little late for that.  My expertise is definitely more in embedded.  When I first converted the libraries and things didn't compile, the solutions I found suggested that I change to multithreaded DLL.  Months later, millions of lines of code converted..  Too late to go back now.  Honestly for the most part, things have worked.  Its just problems like these that have stuck me.  But I see the light at the end of the tunnel.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Paulo Madeira's generous help, I was able to solve this by searching  KB280512 which led me to a project called GPSCom written by PJ Naughter.  Link is here http://www.naughter.com/gpscom2.html.  I downloaded his code and he offers a freeware file named "ATLCPImplMT.h" for use in any form as long as it is unmodified.  Based on his example, I modified the code as follows:

```
HRESULT Fire_Msg(BSTR Msg)
{
    CComCritSecLock<CComAutoCriticalSection> lock(m_CPMTCritSec);

    ATL::CComVariant varResult;
    int nConnections = m_Clients.GetSize();

    int nConnectionIndex;
    ATL::CComVariant* pvars = new ATL::CComVariant[1];

    for (nConnectionIndex = 0; nConnectionIndex < nConnections; nConnectionIndex++)
    {
        ATL::CComPtr<IDispatch> sp;
        if (SUCCEEDED(GetInterfaceAt(nConnectionIndex, sp)))
        {
            VariantClear(&varResult);
            pvars[0] = Msg;
            DISPPARAMS disp = { pvars, NULL, 1, 0 };
            sp->Invoke(0x1, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &disp, &varResult, NULL, NULL);
            if (varResult.scode != S_OK)
            {
                // Do some error handling...  (later)
                return varResult.scode;
            }
        }
    }
    delete [] pvars;
    return varResult.scode;
}
```

This question is a possible duplicate of the one asked here:  [ATL COM: Access Event Methods From Other Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552418/atl-com-access-event-methods-from-other-thread/16559945#16559945).  But to be fair, when I started my searching - I wasn't aware of the right words to search.
Thanks.